# BotFramework loadtesting with BotServiceStressToolkit and MockChannel. Problem to obtain data from MockChannel

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

Maybe I will find anyone, who faced the problem of stress testing for Bot Framework.
I have got acquainted with the chaing MockChannel and BotServiceStressToolkit:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-BlogSamples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel
https://github.com/damadei/BotServiceStressToolkit

initial data:
Bot deployed on azure. MockChannel deployed also in azure (in kubernetes cluster). Try to test from local computer.

I have created MockChannel, published it to azure (to kubernetes) and set up a connection for deployed bot. After configuring Jmeter and new test plan, there is no problem to send messages to bot, and bot also responses to MockChannel. The problem is - I can't connect to my MockChannel for obtain responses from callback server.

And I don't know why it happens. Mb I need to run load tests also in kube. If any have a success history of this combination?

Comment: Are the bot and MockChannel both deployed in the same container? Are the correct ports open? Also please note that `BotServiceStressTestToolkit` isn't "official" and that although the MockChannel/JMeter combination is the most frequent way stress testing is done for BotFramework bots, not many folks seem to do it, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out, that this combination can't provide functionality I want. Also, I didn't able to configure connections between containers (I used different containers, there was hope that it will work). It's only works if you are able to take public and private IP with port forwarding. So we decided to write something own.

Comment: @Samolevar did you find a viable solution for this?